# Angularjs: How to add custom filter to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-filters

My code:

```
        angular.module('app.filters').filter('someFilter', function()
        {
           //some code here
        });
        angular.module('app.directives').directive('myDirective', function() {
           //some code...
            scope: false,
            controller: ['$scope',function($scope, $filter) {
                $scope.evaluate = function (attr) {
                    return = $scope.$eval(attr);
                };
            }],
         });

        angular.module('app',['app.directives', 'app.filters']);
```

the problem is when I call `scope.evaluate(attr)` function on attribute like `"'some_val'|someFilter"`, I recieve 
`[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: someFilterFilterProvider <- someFilterFilter`

in my html it's ok: `<html ng-app='app'>...etc`

Answer (score 0):

angular.module('app.filters') and 
angular.module('app.directives') are two different modules so you just need to use "app" and it should work.

angular.module('app').filter()...
angular.module("app").directive()....

Comment: but they're injected in main module 'app' and something like {{'some_val'|someFilter}} in html works fine! and in my directive i use parent scope, which knows about filters. And yep, I can't change this structure